Ports show as open when nmaping to localhost but filtered when connecting to IP
My 22.04.4 Ubuntu server was installed on a Proxmox VE. Then I installed Discourse forum on top of it (it uses Docker).
Now, after successful installation the Docker's 443/80 ports show as closed when checking from the network.
When running nmap localhost is see this:
root@ubuntu-discourse:~# nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-04-19 08:08 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000070s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

But when doing the same for the IP address or the hostname of the box I see this:
root@ubuntu-discourse:~# nmap 192.168.131.211
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-04-19 08:10 UTC
Nmap scan report for ubuntu-discourse (192.168.131.211)
Host is up (0.0000090s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  open     ssh
80/tcp  filtered http
443/tcp filtered https

From the network I see this:
PS C:\Users\mwojt> nmap 192.168.131.211
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-04-19 10:46 îrodkowoeuropejski czas letni
Nmap scan report for 192.168.131.211
Host is up (0.00041s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  closed http
443/tcp closed https

Here is what is the Docker's port status
root@ubuntu-discourse:~# docker port 6922c7802903
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
80/tcp -> [::]:80
443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:443
443/tcp -> [::]:443

I also enabled firewall, as without enabling it port 22 was visible from the network only:
root@ubuntu-discourse:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

I am not a Linux/Docker expert, so I would appreciate your advice on where to start troubleshooting.
Thanks in advance for your help!
